# hadoop multi node with spark sample job

Tags: apache-spark

I have just configured spark on my Hadoop cluster and i want to run the spark sample job.
before that I want to understand what, this below job code stands for.

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode client --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi $SPARK_HOME/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.0.jar 10
```

Answer (score 3):

You can see all possible parameters for submitting a spark job on [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit). I summarized the ones in your submit script as below:

```
spark-submit 
--deploy-mode client  # client/cluster. default value client. Whether to deploy your driver on the worker nodes or locally

--class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi  # The entry point for your application 

$SPARK_HOME/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.0.jar 10 #jar file path and expected arguments
```

--master is another parameter usually defined in submit scripts. For my HDP cluster default value of master is yarn.  You can see all possible values for master in [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls) again.